# Why does Java read the same byte from broken socket over and over again?

Tags: java, sockets

The client reads the status byte in the loop while it is equal to 0x01:

```
do {
    input.read(magicWord); // ALWAYS THE SAME BYTE AFTER THE SERVER IS GONE
    if (magicWord[0] == (byte) 0xFF)
        break;

    // retrieve the progress
    byte[] cur = new byte[4];
    input.read(cur);

    // and set the progress bar
    progressBar.setValue(ByteBuffer.wrap(cur).getInt());
} while (!isCancelled());
```

But if the server crashes (for example by SIGKILL) while the client is in this loop, the client keeps getting the last `magickWord` sent by the server over and over again (and gets into the endless loop). Even setting `SO_TIMEOUT` doesn't solve the problem. How should the client detect a server failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't read anything at all. `input.read(magicWord)` return `-1`. You `0xFF` byte in your buffer since previous read (`read` method doesn't clear buffer).

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem, but it actually returns -1 when the server is gone.
Weird, that it does not throw an exception though...

Comment: Yes. I will change my answer to reflect `-1` mistake.

Comment: @milos That is not *weird". That is the **expected** behavior. Dont assume how things should work - study them upfront to avoid creating *assumptions* on your end!

Answer (score 1):

That call to [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) returns the number of bytes read. You do not check that result.

And you do not clear your read buffer - thus you keep seeing the same bytes all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

You must check the return value of the `read` call. Look it up in the documentation and write your code accordingly.